# Get value from checkbox in SapUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a main.controller.js where I want to check the value of a Checkbox. If the checkbox has been checked, the first flexbox will be shown  and the second flexbox will not be shown in the fragment.

This my controller.js:

```js
checkDone: function () {
    var checkV = this.byId("ch1").getSelected();// not working
}
```

This my **fragment.xml**

```xml
<CheckBox id="ch1" select ="checkDone" text="Check"></CheckBox>
<FlexBox class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd" id="f1">
    <Input value=""></Input>
</FlexBox>
<FlexBox direction="Column" id="f2">
    <Input value=""></Input>
</FlexBox>
```

Comment: Accessing the absolute id might not work as it can be prefixed with the Id of the View.

Comment: @hirse That is true when you are accessing from DOM. View.byId function is defined in OpenUI5 View class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works (see example with sap.m.Checkbox [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vladdy/djnezuL1/2/)).

Just a recommendation: in your checkbox's 'select' handler you use:

```
this.byId("ch1").getSelected();
```

in order to whether the checkbox is selected or not, but this value is already given as a parameter of the select handler:

```
checkDone: function (oEvent) {
     var bSelected = oEvent.getParameter('selected'));
}
```

Simmilar is for the sap.ui.commons.Checkbox API. Check [change event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.CheckBox.html#event:change).

Comment: Thanks your comment. I tried `var sel = oEvent.getParameter('selected');`
 . It is work. But `checkV` didn't work.

Comment: Woudl you please share your code in jsdiffle or something simmilar, so it can be really visible what is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getSelected()` try `getChecked()`.

`getChecked()` will return true or false based on checked/unchecked.

Comment: `sap.ui.commons.CheckBox` has `getChecked()`, the CheckBox from the mobile library uses `getSelected()`. Based on the usage of the other Controls, it looks more like `sap.m.CheckBox` to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `View.byId` function returns an element in its initial form. When you find element from `DOM`, `getSelected()` function works as expected.